# ActiveRecord Polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I have a project that allows users to have conversations with other users.
Conversations can contain multiple users via a `UserConversations` modal. 
`UserConversations` need to be polymorphic so that they can also belong to `Chatrooms`. However, when I add the polymorphic association my relationships break.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
end

class UserConversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, as: :context, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_conversations, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end

class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :messages, as: :context, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_conversations, as: :parent, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end


2.3.1 :009 > user = User.first
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC 
LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Loi Tran", email: "loi@coderschool.vn", 
password_digest: "$2a$10$eDZ6IyTAzVK4qNvJfIhPP.3fhEIhdv0bWuVqrTjJk86...",         
image_url: "https://scontent.fsgn5-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p3...",         
created_at: "2017-08-21 07:20:11", updated_at: "2017-08-29 18:47:04", city: 
"Tallahassee", state: "Florida", position: "Getting yelled at", school: 
"Florida State University", quote: "If it was easy, everyone would do it.", 
avatar: nil, last_name: "Tran", first_name: "Loi">

2.3.1 :010 > user.user_conversations
  UserConversation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "user_conversations".* FROM 
"user_conversations" WHERE "user_conversations"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  
[["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<UserConversation id: 453, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-09-10 06:01:27", updated_at: "2017-09-10 06:01:27", parent_type: "Chatroom", parent_id: 8>, #<UserConversation id: 454, user_id: 1, created_at: "2017-09-10 06:02:22", updated_at: "2017-09-10 06:02:22", parent_type: "Conversation", parent_id: 318>]>

2.3.1 :011 > user.conversations
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  class
    from (irb):11
```

I'm using `Rails 5.1.3` & `ruby 2.3.1`

I need user.conversations to work. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two join models instead, its both simpler and will avoid the major cons of polymorphism:

- No foreign key support as the DB does not know what table the association points to.
- Joins are tricky since you have to query the table to know what table to join. Which is really bad for a join table.

Since join tables just consist of two columns and the model has very little logic using polymorphism does not really give you anything but headaches.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations
  has_many :chatroom_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :chatrooms, through: :chatroom_users
end

class UserConversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, as: :context, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_conversations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end

class ChatroomUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :chatroom
end

class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
  has_many :messages, as: :context, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :chatroom_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_chatrooms
end
```

Comment: In general you really want to avoid polymorphism if possible. When you just discover polymorphism its like "wow this is amazing, I'm going to use this for everything" and then the performance nightmares start popping up. The  message class is a very valid use though.

Comment: I think I may have marked your answer correct a little bit too quickly, I've tried implementing it now and I can't seem to get the `Chatroom` model to work correctly, lemme check again and get back to you.

Comment: Ooops, should be `has_many :chatroom_users, dependent: :destroy`.

Comment: I marked it as correct, but for future readers, we also need to change `# Conversation.rb` to `has_many :user_conversations, dependent: :destroy` since we've removed the polymorphic association.

Answer (score 0):

According to rails documentation when using **has_many through** (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), if we consider UserConversation is the middle table between User and conversations, it should be something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations 
end
```

and

```
class UserConversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation
end
```

and

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_conversations
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end
```

Put the rest of your relations and `:dependent` again.

Comment: Yeah this is how I originally had it so that it worked for a conversation with many users. However I needed to model `UserConversations` differently(to allow it to belong to both a `Chatroom` or a `Conversation`. Any ideas on that? =)

Comment: After some search i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128308/rails-many-to-many-polymorphic-relationships) i hope this would help you, If i got a final solution to this issue i'm gonna leave a comment.
I think this could help too. [link](http://cobwwweb.com/rails-has-many-through-polymorphic-association).

Comment: I wrote a method to find the conversations, it's not what I want to do but I guess it'll have to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the result I was looking for(finding a users conversations). It's not as elegant as I would like but I think it serves the purpose.

```
# user.rb

def conversations
  Conversation.where(id: user_conversations.where(parent_type: 
  "Conversation").map(&:parent_id))
end
```

Comment: It's not defining the relationships the way I would like but it does find the correct conversations for the user.